# Seaborn plot not showing all plots with a loop

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

```
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
parm = ['ALTERSKATEGORIE_GROB', 'ANREDE_KZ', 'CJT_GESAMTTYP', 'FINANZ_MINIMALIST', 'FINANZ_SPARER', 'FINANZ_VORSORGER']

for y in parm:
    plot =  sns.countplot(x=y, data=azdias_under_20)
    print (plot);

Output:
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
```

I am getting the above output, and just one plot (not seen here) of the last list item (''FINANZ_VORSORGER').
It is in a Jupyter notebook.
Why I am not seeing all the plots, but just the last one?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if it would work, but try `plot.show()` before `print(plot)`; and why are you printing the plot?

Comment: It did not work.  I am printing the plot because I need to show count frequencies on some columns of my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not show the plot in each iteration, you can do it using `matplotlib` :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
parm = ['ALTERSKATEGORIE_GROB', 'ANREDE_KZ', 'CJT_GESAMTTYP', 'FINANZ_MINIMALIST', 'FINANZ_SPARER', 'FINANZ_VORSORGER']

for y in parm:
    sns.countplot(x=y, data=azdias_under_20)
    plt.show()
```

**UPDATE**
You asked why your code didn't work. `plt.show()` is a method that shows all of the plots you draw before you show. so if you draw one plot and write `plt.show()` it will show it. but if you draw many plots, and then you write `plt.show()` it will mix all of them and show them all. for more information check [this link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) . look at the following example :

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> c = [2,3,4,5,6]
>>> d = [1,4,9,16,25]
>>> plt.plot(a,b)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x00000180CF934C18>]
>>> plt.plot(a,c)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x00000180CB39AA58>]
>>> plt.plot(a,d)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x00000180CF934F60>]
>>> plt.show()
```

the resulting plot would be :

[image]

Comment: Worked !!!! thx !!

Why in my answer, it is not showing in each iteration?

And how can I show 2 plots (not from the same dataset) side by side? thx

Comment: check out my answer again

Comment: excellent.

And how can I show 2 plots (not from the same dataset) side by side?

Comment: @DanMintz you should ask side by side plots in another question, but you can do it using `subplot`'s in `matplotlib`.

Comment: you can check this link for subplots : https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html?highlight=subplot#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot